# Причина вызова 404?

Tags: php, pdo

Есть две страницы. На которых один и тот же код работает по разному.

Первая страница, проверяет код в URL и если всё хорошо, меняет значение в БД.

Вторая страница, не даёт зайти если код имеет вот такой вид "ufyptgb2o0mnxl34ejv8" (хотя вот такой вид "1e2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9ps5" не вызывает ошибку, если вводить просто буквы или просто цифры).

Данные коды берутся из URL, который отправляется пользователям на почту имеет он такой вид site.net/page?code=1232323k2123kj. Что-то типа такого. На одной странице он работает нормально. На другой нет и вызывает ошибку. Я уже закомментировал все строчки php-кода, и оставил только HTML. Ошибка не исчезает.

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);//Убираем Notice, а все остальные ошибки выводим

require_once 'connection.php';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pb', $user, $pass);

$codePass = $_GET['codePass'];

/*$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT CP FROM u WHERE CP = :codePass');
$stmt->bindParam(':codePass', $codePass);
$stmt->execute();*/

print_r($codePass);

/*if($codePass == 0){
    header('Location: error404.html');
}*/

/*while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  $_SESSION['codePass'] = $result->CodePassword;
}*/

//var_dump($code);

/*$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE u SET Password = :newPass WHERE CP = :codePass');
$stmt->bindParam(':codePass', $codePass);
$stmt->bindParam(':newPass', $newPass);
$stmt->execute();*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Смена пароля</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="newPass" type="password" placeholder="Создайте новый пароль" required>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="Button" placeholder="Подтвердить" required>
        </form>
        <p>Ваш пароль был изменён</p>
        <button onclick="document.location='enter.php'">Войти</button>
    </div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Я уже закомментировал все строчки php-кода, и оставил только HTML Можно пример полного скрипта, что вы используете, либо это CMS?

Comment: Наша задача - угадать текст ошибки?

Comment: @Zerxa изменён и добавлен.

Comment: причина в том, что apache или что у вас там, не может найти файл `page` и шлёт вам 404

Comment: @ArchDemon не могу понять, что за page.